# How to display data vertically in matrix control SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an ssrs report which display data in a table just like image1.

[image: image1]

I need to display data vertically in two tables to avoid extra pages. Just like image2.

[image: image2]

Currently I have tried matrix control with row group and column group but it is displaying data horizontaly see image3.

[image: image3]

Below are the group expression.

Row Group : `=ceiling(rownumber(nothing) / 2)`

Column Group : `=ceiling(rownumber(nothing) mod 2)`

Can anyone suggest to me how to display it vertically just like img2.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a sollution for this, posting it here as might be someone else may require it. Use bellow expressions for groups.

Row Group : =ceiling(rownumber(nothing) mod (Fields!RecCount.Value / 2))

Column Group : =ceiling(rownumber(nothing) / (Fields!RecCount.Value / 2))

Where RecCount is the total row count of data set. This will divide the result set into two parallel tables. If more or less then two tables are required then increase or decrease devisor accordingly.